# Django-admin.py not being recognized suddenly

Tags: python, django

I tried starting a new Django project yesterday but when I did "django-admin.py startproject projectname" I got an error stating: "django-admin.py is not recognized as an internal or external command." The strange thing is, when I first installed Django, I made a few projects and everything worked fine. But now after going back a few months later it has suddenly stopped working.

I've tried looking around for an answer and all I could find is that this typically has to do with the system path settings, however, I know that I have the proper paths set up so I don't understand what's happening. Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Test if you are able to import django in your python commandline

Comment: Yes, it will recognize a django import.

Comment: what os you are using , win32 or unix-based ?

Comment: ok, so check the c:\python2x\scripts for the `django-admin.py`.

Comment: Aha! It's missing from the scripts folder. How can I restore the file?

Comment: install pip, then uninstall django by pip command, and reinstall it again by pip.see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the django was installed properly.

```
import django
```

**EDIT 1**

If you got exception, try to uninstall and install django.

i recommend to do this by pip:

```
$> easy_install pip


$> pip uninstall django
$> pip install django
```

Then check the file `C:\Python26\Scripts\django-admin.py` exists.
you may replace `c:\python26` by your local python installation path.
if you not found the file, so uninstall and install django, see **EDIT 1** above.

then add `C:\Python26` and `C:\Python26\Scripts` to your path. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-xp)

From [python documents](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html):

> to the current setting for the PATH environment variable, which you will find in the properties window of “My Computer” under the “Advanced” tab. Note that if you have sufficient privilege you might get a choice of installing the settings either for the Current User or for System. The latter is preferred if you want everybody to be able to run Python on the machine.

Comment: The file is missing from the scripts folder. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Jen, I recommend you to use virtualenv and pip together to working on django.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling django and now the django-admin.py file is in the scripts folder but when I try to execute anything with django-admin.py it just opens the django-admin file in Notepad++

Comment: I ran that line and got: "python: can't open file 'path\to\django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: wow, change `path\to\django-admin.py` with your c:\python26\scripts\django-admin.py' file.

Answer (score 1):

i am totally new to coding, so pardon my amateur answers.

I had similar problem - i realized that while my Django was installed on C Drive, my files were saved on D drive and i was trying to run django-admin from D drive in the command prompt which was giving the above error. what worked for me was the following

1. Located the Django-admin.exe and django-admin.py file which was in below path 
   C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts>
2. copied both these files into the D drive folder where i was trying to create new projects
3. then on the terminal command prompt (which was set to D Drive projects) ran django-admin startproject [filename] and it created a new file [filename]in that folder and this error was resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following code

`py -m django startproject add_your_project_name_here`

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/) you may try,

`python -m django <command> [options]`.

Where python is the version of the python you are using.

Usage `python -m django startproject <projectname>`.